# How can we export all transactions between tween ledger numbers from stellar?

Tags: history, xdr

I need to export all the transactions and the data associated with them between two ledger points. I am guessing I need to get it from history files. How do I find out which json files I need to use and how can I translate from XDR to ascii. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Horizon and iterate over the ledgers and associated txs/ops that you are interested in? It might take a little while (depending on your set size) but it will give you all data in JSON.

Comment: The volume is very high and it is not going to be a one time operation.

Comment: I am looking at it from the angle of using https://github.com/stellar/go/tree/master/tools/stellar-archivist#dumping-an-xdr-file-from-an-archive-as-json